# How can I forecast next sequential binary data?

Tags: forecasting, sequential

I am trying to forecast next number.

The number can be only 1 and -1.
And i have sequential history datas of 1 and -1.

1 -1 1 1 1 -1 -1 1....

I want to implement this with python.

I have tried arima and some other complex codes,
but they were to hard to implement.
I want a simple solution.

How can i implement this with python ?

Comment: `random.randrange(-1, 2, 2)` should work with acceptable accuracy

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.   Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Without specifying the requirements, not sure what you want.

Here it is a simple one, always the inverse of the last appeared one.

```
exist = [1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1]
predict = exist[-1]*-1
```

---

Here is another one, try to go close to half population.

```
exist = [1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1]
predict = 1 if sum(exist) > 0 else -1
```

---

Here is another one, random (from @Iłya Bursov )

```
predict = random.randrange(-1, 2, 2)
```